# Flask/SQLAlchemy - How to globally use latin-1 instead of UTF-8?

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a web application written using Flask, SQLAlchemy, and MySQL.  When I get strings submitted via form (e.g. `request.form['Username']`) they are submitted through SQLAlchemy and ultimately to MySQL as Unicode strings.  My database is using the latin-1 charset, so I'm really looking to use latin-1 throughout.  Is there a way to force Flask or SQLAlchemy to always use/convert to latin-1 without manually doing `string.encode('latin-1')`?

As an example of how this causes problems, when I do a `SELECT...WHERE Name=:name` and provide `request.form['Name']` as the bound parameter, it's going through as `u'Some Name'` and therefore not finding any matches.

Comment: One comment that definitely is not a helpful answer: I strongly believe you are moving in the wrong direction. You should strive to use UTF-8 troughout, not the other way round. I cannot see any reason to stick to Latin-1, especially since you are handling user input there, as I can see. Latin-1 will not suffice. My Polish friends will surely agree.

Comment: I'm sure that's true generally, however this is a system for internal use by only several people, and will not require any special characters.

Comment: And 640K should be enough for everybody. Sorry, could not resist. Systems have a fatal tendency to evolve, and I’ve faced too many encoding issues recently.

Comment: I'll definitely take your comments to heart and consider. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the encoding of the SQLAlchemy connection to MySQL in the connection parameters:

```
create_engine('mysql+mysqldb:///mydb?charset=latin1')
```

See the [SQLAlchemy documentation on MySQL, unicode section](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#unicode).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get home and have access to my code!

Answer (score 2):

First, read the unicode chapter on Flask website at:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/unicode/. 
It says "if you are using non-Unicode characters in your Python files you have to tell Python which encoding your file uses."

To do this, you can add the following in beginning of the python file. This tells the interpreter what encoding to use.

```
# coding: latin1
```